# How to use jointjs with reactjs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jointjs

I want to use jointjs library with reactjs.
Is there any library or wrapper available which can be used? If not available then what is the simplest way to use it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the npm module [joint](https://github.com/clientIO/joint) with your react project.

This module provides the functionality of the diagramming library. It can be used to create either static diagrams or, and more importantly, fully interactive diagramming tools and application builders.

Please see http://jointjs.com for more information, demos and documentation.

Please check the example for combining react.js with JointJS repo from [here](https://github.com/santoshshinde2012/reactjs-jointjs-example).

[image]

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

I published on npm [`react.joint`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react.joint), a React wrapper that simplifies the integration of JointJS with React by using the `foreignObject` feature of `svg` to render React components as nodes or ports instead of relying on JointJS's JSON markup